# Is there a way to insert documentation comments into a VIM macro definition?

Tags: vimrc, comments

I have found VI / VIM macros extremely obtuse to understand even a week after I've written them. The syntax of a `.vimrc` file supports comments on lines beginning with a doublequote character (`"`) and that helps. I can write paragraphs of notes to myself that way, but it would be really useful to be able to break up a macro definition to comment about each step of what it's doing.

Any ideas?

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]! Can you give an example macro? I can think of a way to use string concatenation on register-based macros, but key-mappings might be harder.

Comment: I don't know the viability of this, but could you use a `foo_macro` variable? Then each following line would add part of the macro and could have a comment: `let foo_macro+='$'  " go to end of line`. Then at the end have an `nnoremap <expr> :exec 'normal! ' . foo_macro` (substituting `nnoremap` for whatever mode you want)?

Answer (score 1):

A Vim macro is just text stored in a register, which is taken to represent normal mode commands.

Perhaps you could write commented Vimscript functions that constructed and returned a command string, like this:

```
func MakeMacro() 
    let l:m = ""
    " some comment
    let l:m .= "ifoo"
    " some other comment
    let l:m .= "\<Esc>"
    return l:m
endfunction
```

After sourcing the function, you would assign its result to a Vim register:

```
:let @a=MakeMacro()
```

And invoke it in normal mode like a typical recorded macro:

```
@a
```

See `:h let` (for the `let @a` syntax) and `:h .=`. See also `:h expr-string` for the syntax that allows including special keys like `<Esc>`.

Comment: Fantastic answer, welcome to [vi.se]! This is what I was envisioning in my comment, though it doesn't work quite as well for the map family.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks @danidiaz and @Jake,

You both seem to be heading down similar paths and I had not even thought of doing it that way.

Here's what I came up with as a 2D `.vimrc` comment display format directly in the `.vimrc` file. Let me know what you think.

```
"
"= GENERIC CLIPBOARD YANK  <F2>y (Y for Yank)
"= Yank the entire contents of the file into the clipboard; quit without saving.
"
"define F2 followed by y to be:
"|      Go to line 1.
"|      | From there, into the * buffer (system clipboard),
"|      | | yank to the end of the file.
"|      | | | Go to sleep for 1 second (to allow the clipboard to be updated).
"|      | | | |  Quit without saving the file.
"|      | | | |  |
map #2y 1G"*yG1gs:q!<CR>
"-------"-"-"-"--"------
```

I've flagged two lines above with `"=` at the beginning of each, so that they can become the User Help. Then a grep command could search for `"^\"= "`. Here's the command I used.

```
grep -B 1 -E "^\"= " ~/.vimrc
```

I'm not sure if the `-E` for Extended Regular Expressions is needed and I like the `-B 1` to include one line previous to a matching sequence, so in the `.vimrc` fragment above, I have an explicitly empty comment line.

I can easily make a shell script for that and execute it with a `!` command inside `vim`. I'm looking at how I might do that easily from inside `vim`, without the shell command, but that's a little lower priority.

Thanks again.

Comment: :nnoremap would be preferrable to :map, it avoids unexpected interactions . If we want to define a mapping that performs complex actions, at some point it pays to go the full route of: defining a function that performs the actions (possibly involving commands like :normal)  then creating a command that invokes the function, finally creating a mapping that invokes the command. That process is described here: https://benjaminpetersen.com/vim-commands/ and here https://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/. As for user help, perhaps the standard Vim help format could be used (:h help-writing)

Comment: Re grep in vim... see `:help :grep` and `:help :vim`